# Error in distance formula in matlab

Tags: matlab

I got an error:

```
Error using - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in check dists = sqrt((cols - centroidX ).^2 + (rows - centroidY).^2);
```

How do I resolve that error?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  This is a programming question, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I resolve that error?

Obviously, reading the error is the first and most important step:

```
Error using - 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```

Matlab says it can't subtract to Matrices that don't have the same dimension.

So either `cols` and `centroidX` don't have the same size, or `rows` and `centroidY` don't have the same size, or both.

Comment: I have 2 objects in my image and i have to calculate the max distance between the centroid and the boundary pixels what should i do

Comment: *no matter* what you do -- you have a dimensional mismatch, and that's what Matlab's complaining about.